# When I measure position again after a very short time, can't I calculate momentum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-optics

In quantum optics, there are squeezed states that are very precise in one quadrature. You can analoguously have state squeezed in position instead of one quadrature. Can I perhaps make a slightly more bold bet, where the electron is going to be after the third short time interval measurement, than just the quantum mechanical "It could be anywhere. Momentum is maximally undefined"?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/768504/28512

Comment: … and see also [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/773556/36194)